With tikz and scopes why is the third scope on top of the second
I have the following LaTeX using TikZ and Tikz Scopes to draw some fields.
Three too be exact.
However, for the last field c_3 I get that belonging scope is ontop of the previous scope for c_2, see picture below.

The code I use for rendering this picture can be reduced to what is below. I am sure it is something minor but I simply cannot spot what it is.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
      minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
      outer sep=0pt, on chain},
    ]

    \node[] (c1) {$c_1:$};
    \begin{scope}[start chain = B1 going right, right of=c1, node distance=0]
      \foreach \i in {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    \node[X] {\i};
  \end{scope}

  \node[below of=c1] (c2) {$c_2:$};
  \begin{scope}[start chain = B2 going right, right of=c2, below of=c1, node distance=0]
          \foreach \i in {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
    \node[X] {\i};
  \end{scope}


  \node[below of=c2] (c3) {$c_3:$};

  \begin{scope}[start chain = B3 going right, right of=c3, below of=c2, node distance=0]
    \foreach \i in {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    \node[X] {\i};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You load the positioning library but don't use its keys (= before the of) outside of chains. You can't apply multiple of them, the last one wins (with the old of = form it's even messier). I'd make the c nodes part of the chain and just place the first below the first one of above.

That is one weird bug!  The confusing part is that the original code almost works and doesn't generate error messages.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
%\usetikzlibrary{math}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
      minimum width=2ex, minimum height=3ex,
      outer sep=0pt, on chain, right},
    ]

    \node[] (c1) {$c_1:$};
    \begin{scope}[start chain = B1, shift=(c1.east), node distance=0]
      \foreach \i in {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    {\node[X] {\i};};
  \end{scope}

  \node[below of=c1] (c2) {$c_2:$};
  
  \begin{scope}[start chain = B2, shift=(c2.east), node distance=0]
          \foreach \i in {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}
    {\node[X] {\i};};
  \end{scope}

  \node[below of=c2] (c3) {$c_3:$};

  \begin{scope}[start chain = B3, shift=(c3.east), node distance=0]
    \foreach \i in {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    {\node[X] {\i};};
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you so much!
